# My apps can"t show any logs

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

While developing apps with Android Studio

[No Filters](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/1F4oLAqa-k2IariS2dwqH8mSJIkPAjRNo-WOc6lWRI8=w540-h215-p-no) show all the system log except my app

[My apps](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/PTuQheWjQrlMSCZtqljs3DAc0YczCSD23ipcwZhnk1I=w649-h215-p-no) show nothing

How to figure it out?

Comment: Rule of StackOverflow Number 1: Post code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oky, I have found the answer :In Android studio 1.0.2 or later: you should enable ADB integration through Tools -> Android, before run your app .